# Do I need to partition my hard drive before I install Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, partitioning

Do I need to do that manually, does the Windows Installer do it for me, or do I need to do it at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Best way is to create a partition with Windows CD for C drive. But make sure you have some unpartitioned space for Ubuntu. Boot from the Ubuntu CD and choose the option which says unused space. This will create a dual boot without loosing the data on your windows partition.  For more info on that see [Installing Ubuntu Desktop](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-desktop)

If you are installing using Wubi, Wubi will create a virtual partition.  Wubi lets you install and uninstall Ubuntu from a Windows desktop just like a windows application. It will add an Ubuntu entry to the Windows boot menu. For more info see the [Wubi Guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide/)

Comment: So if I use Wubi, I don't need to do anything special, just install it?

Comment: Right.  Just run it.  To Download Wubi [Click Here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer)

Comment: Thanks for explaining it to me. I wasn't sure what to do because a lot of people told me to partition my hard drive first and I wasn't sure how to do that. I didn't think I needed to partition it. Once again, thank-you.